# jQuery Flot vertical bar chart tooltip position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in jQuery Flot chart. Now I try to implement a vertical bar chart in my web application. Everything works fine, but a problem the tool tip position appear in the back screen. Please see the below image (tool tip in red box).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is - update the tooltip class z-index to much higher.

.tooltip  { z-index: 9999; }